# How do i change a text view set in an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sdk

In activity A, the user gives input which is received in Activity B. If the user clicks the TextView in the second activity, they are taken to Activity C. In Act. C the user is able to edit the TextView from Activities A and B and I want the edited text to be set as the new TextView in Activity B. To recap... User makes text in A. text goes to B. If user wants to edit text in B, they are taken to C where they can edit the text. How do i make that New text set in Activity C substitute the original TextView in B (after the user finishes editing the textview they are taken back to activity B.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Intent.

In C.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("TEXT",newText);
startActivity(intent);
```

In B.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String msg = intent.getStringExta("Text")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start the activity for result, then handle the data when it is returned.  See the guide in the Activity class: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)